# shell scripts how to replace string between 2 characters in all lines start with specific string?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, sed, awk

I have a text file like below, I want to replace the old string between 2 characters(in this case is `^` and `|`) with new string (in this case will be replaced to old string `^` old string)if the line start with specific string (in this example is `MMX`.

text file original:

```
General start, this is a test file.
TAG okay, this line not need to be processed.
MMX ABCD ^string1|other strings abc
CCF ABCD ^string2|other strings cde, skip line
MMX CDEE ^String3|other strings aaa
MMX AAAA ^String4|other strings bbb
CCD BBBB ^String5|other strings ccc, skip line
```

text file after modify should be:

```
General start, this is a test file.
TAG okay, this line not need to be processed.
MMX ABCD ^string1^String1|other strings abc
CCF ABCD ^string2|other strings cde, skip line
MMX CDEE ^String3^String3|other strings aaa
MMX AAAA ^String4^String4|other strings bbb
CCD BBBB ^String5|other strings ccc, skip line
```

How can I use shell scripts to perform this job?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using `sed`:

```
sed '/^MMX/s/\(\^[^|]*\)/\1\1/' file.txt
```

Results:

```
General start, this is a test file.
TAG okay, this line not need to be processed.
MMX ABCD ^string1^string1|other strings abc
CCF ABCD ^string2|other strings cde, skip line
MMX CDEE ^String3^String3|other strings aaa
MMX AAAA ^String4^String4|other strings bbb
CCD BBBB ^String5|other strings ccc, skip line
```

Comment: @user1831356: If this solution, or any other solution here, has worked for you, you should consider accepting it by clicking the accept tick to the left of your favorite answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness:

```
$ awk '/^MMX/{sub(/\^[^|]+/,"&&")}1' file
General start, this is a test file.
TAG okay, this line not need to be processed.
MMX ABCD ^string1^string1|other strings abc
CCF ABCD ^string2|other strings cde, skip line
MMX CDEE ^String3^String3|other strings aaa
MMX AAAA ^String4^String4|other strings bbb
CCD BBBB ^String5|other strings ccc, skip line
```

but I'd use one of the posted sed solutions since this is a simple substitution on a single line which is what sed is good at.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide `sed` with an "address", which is a filter for the lines that the command is executed on:

```
sed '/^MMX/s/\^(.*)\|/^\1^\1|/g'
```

in this case, the address is `/^MMX/`, the command is `s///g`, and it replaces `\^(.*)\|` with `^\1^\1|`, where `\1` is the part in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -plne "if(/^MMX/){$_=~s/([^\^]*)([^\|]*)(.*)/$1$2$2$3/g;}" your_file
```

tested below:

```
>perl -plne "if(/^MMX/){$_=~s/([^\^]*)([^\|]*)(.*)/$1$2$2$3/g;}" new.txt
General start, this is a test file.
TAG okay, this line not need to be processed.
MMX ABCD ^string1^string1|other strings abc
CCF ABCD ^string2|other strings cde, skip line
MMX CDEE ^String3^String3|other strings aaa
MMX AAAA ^String4^String4|other strings bbb
CCD BBBB ^String5|other strings ccc, skip line
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure capitalization in the new string:

```
sed '/^MMX/s/\^\([^|]\+\)/^\1^\u\1/'
```

Comment: Shortcuts like `\u` are restricted to GNU sed.  As a general rule, they should be avoided for portability.

Answer (score -2):

sed s/^MMX([^^]*)^([^|]*)\|(.+)/MMX\1^\2^\2\|\3/ fileName

Comment: not working, give this message:
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: Go to vi and in command mode do :1,$s/^MMX\([^^]*\)^\([^|]*\)\|\(.+\)/MMX\1^\2^\2\|\3/